# Can't we omit database triggers?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, architecture, database-trigger

As Wikipedia says

> Database Triggers are commonly used to:
>
> - audit changes (e.g. keep a log of the users and roles involved in
>   changes)
> - enhance changes (e.g. ensure that every change to a record
>   is time-stamped by the server's clock)
> - enforce business rules (e.g.
>   require that every invoice have at least one line item) etc.

ref: [database triggers - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)

But we can do these things inside the Business Layer using a common programming language (especially with OOP) easily. So what is the necessity of database triggers in modern software architecture? Why do we really need them?

Comment: They're among other things very useful for auditing that no one opens an SQL manager and changes things around under the hood without alerting the business layer. In other words, think HIPAA/PCI/...

Comment: As long as you can prohibit any and all access to the data from outside your Business Layer, and no one working on your BL used an enbugger, everything should be perfect. It goes without saying that the specifications for the BL were flawless and implemented precisely. The rest of us will continue to use them to handle odd rules ("Usernames must be unique among active accounts."), denormalization (Keep totals up-to-date without running a SUM.), logging, ... .

Comment: I may prefer to have some special logics in DB(Triggers,SPs etc..) even though I can do all business logic in business layer, when I need to think more about performance than maintenance etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might work, if all data is changed by your application only. But there are other cases which I have seen very frequently:

1. There are other applications (like batch jobs doing imports etc.) which do not use the business layer
2. You cannot use plain SQL scripts as a means for hotfixes easily

Apart from that in some cases you can even combine both worlds: Define a trigger in the database, and use Java to implement it. PostgreSql for examples supports triggers written in Java. As for Oracle, you can call a Java method from a PL/SQL trigger. You can define CLR based triggers in MS SQL Server.

This way not every programmer needs to learn PL/SQL, and *data integrity* is enforced by the *database*.

Comment: i really love to hear that there is a way to call a method in our application from a database trigger. i accept your point. thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2):

Think about the performance. IF this is all to be done from the application, there are most likely a lot of extra sql*net round trips, slowing down the application. Having those actions defined in the database makes sure that they are always enforced, not only when the application is used to access the data.

When the database is in control, you have your rules defined on the central location, the database, instead of in many locations in the application.

Comment: Having rules defined in the database doesn't necessarily mean using triggers. It could mean using a PL/SQL stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can completely omit database triggers.

**However**, if you can't guarantee that your database will only be accessed from the application layer (which is impossible) then you need them. Yes, you can perform all your database logic in the application layer but if you have a table that  *needs* X done to it when you're updating it then the only way to do that is in a trigger. If you don't then people accessing your database directly, outside your application, will break your application.

There is nothing else you can do. If you need a trigger, use one. Do not assume that all connections to your database will be through your application...

Comment: great! i got your point and thank you very much for the simplified answer.